# ts7053 Error when iterating over an object in a Svelte component

Tags: typescript, svelte

I've worked out solutions to this issue when just writing Typescript, but I'm having trouble finding a solution for a Svelte component. I get ts7053 error because it doesn't like me using what it apparently thinks is random text for a key on the object.  The key isn't random of course - it's drawn from the object itself so I have no concern about getting an invalid key.  I'm unable to //@ts-ignore this in Svelte, however.  Any suggestions?

error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type ‘string' can't be used to index type 'Prefs'

```
{#each Object.entries($tempPrefs) as [key, value]}
    <div style="width: 31em; padding:1em 1em">
        {#each value.enumChoices as choice}
            <label>
                <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    bind:group={$tempPrefs[key].value} // <--- Lint error here
                    name={key + "choices"}
                    value={choice}
                />
                {camelCaseToTitleCase(choice)}
            </label>
        {/each}
    </div>
{/each}
```

EDIT: I neglected to include the types used by $tempPrefs...

```
export const tempPrefs: Writable<Prefs> = writable(new Prefs())

export class Preference {
    prompt: string
    inputType: InputType
    value: any
    enumChoices: string[] | undefined
    rangeStart: number | undefined
    rangeEnd: number | undefined
    rangeStep: number | undefined
}
export class Prefs {
    rulesName: Preference
    investmentAmountUnit: Preference
    investmentAmount: Preference
    holdPositionsTimeLimit: Preference
    positionsLimit: Preference
    sessions: Preference
    trailingStopPct: Preference
    takeProfit: Preference
    dipMod: Preference
    floor: Preference
}
```

Comment: Please include the actual error text; do you think everyone just knows what TS7053 is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$tempPrefs[key]` should be the same as `value` from the outer `#each`, no need to use the indexer.

If index access has to be used for reactivity, options are limited. One workaround while code in the markup [is not processed](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/4701), is to move type issues to the script, e.g. you can wrap `Object.entries`:

```js
const entries = <K extends string, V>(o: Record<K, V>) =>
    Object.entries(o) as [K, V][];
```

```html
{#each entries($tempPrefs) ...
```

Comment: That still produces the same error. The issue is Typescript treats the keys returned by Object.entries(or keys) as strings, which cannot be used to index the object.

Comment: I am telling you to *not* index the object, because you already have what it would return. If your code is correct then `$tempPrefs[key].value` can be replaced with `value.value`.

Comment: That works when just displaying the data but it doesn't provide a working pointer back to the source object.  The source object doesn't get updated upon changes when I do it that way.  Only referencing the object with a key works for making changes.  I'm not sure why because I don't think this is what happens in Typescript natively, but that's what's happening with Svelte.

Comment: I amended my answer.

Comment: I feel like we're getting somewhere, but I'm getting another TS error likely because I didn't originally include the type info for $tempPrefs (I updated my original post). The error is on the line {#each value.enumChoices as choice}.  There's another one after that as well but I think it's linked to this one.  Here's the error: Argument of type 'string[] | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ArrayLike<unknown>'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ArrayLike<unknown>'.ts(2345)

Comment: You obviously can't iterate `undefined`, either clean up your data beforehand or add something like `(value.enumChoices ?? [])` to ensure there is something.